# Filter a column by names that include same characters

Tags: sql, filter, sql-like

I want to filter a title column by its name (from jobs table). I want to include 'director' job positions, but not 'subdirector' job positions. How can I do it?

This is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
select distinct title, id  from jobs
where title like '%director%' and title not like '%sub%'
```

Comment: title like '%director%' and title not like '%sub%'. And if case matters, wrap with lower.

Comment: Please provide sample data, and your expectations for that sample data. And specify what DBMS you're using.

Comment: This I already try it and it still appear subdirector positions... @isolated

Comment: Your query is different than mine. Also, you mentioned "job" column, but the query references the "title" column. That could be the problem, too.

Comment: After exectuing this code :                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                              
 select distinct title, id  from jobs
where title like '%director%' and title not like '%sub%'                                            
I can find positions like these ones:                                     
director of finance （Owner ）// Subdirector/a //Subdirector de Talento y Cultura

Comment: Like I mentioned, case matters. You may need to convert. such as lower(title) not like '%sub%'.

Comment: @Isolated Okay it was due to the lower case, so I have to include both options: title not like '%sub%' and title not like '%Sub%', correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case matters, so try something like this:

```
    select distinct title, id  
      from jobs
     where lower(title) like '%director%' 
       and lower(title) not like '%sub%'
```

Your dbms may not recognize "lower", so check documentation online to see if it needs to be "lower", or "lcase", or something else.

If using postgres, you could use "ilike", which ignores case:

```
    select distinct title, id  
      from jobs
     where title ilike '%director%' 
       and title not ilike '%sub%'
```

Comment: Oh perfect, yes I'm using postgres, so I will use ILIKE, thanks!